# FrozenGridView  in update panel is not accessable

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a `RealWorld.Grids.FrozenGridView` and after selecting several checkboxes (in the last column) on the grid I try to access the rows in the C# file to run some tasks on the selected rows, but the grid comes up as null, and when I try to findcontrol from the page based on the name of the grid the result is null.

```
gridname = (RealWorld.Grids.FrozenGridView)this.FindControl("gridname") as RealWorld.Grids.FrozenGridView;
```

the grid is located in an updatepanel so to access the grid I include the update panel in the find control as such:

```
UpdatePanel up1 = new UpdatePanel();
    up1.ID = "updatepanelID";
    Label gn = (Label)up1.FindControl("labelname");
```

I also tried:

```
label lbl = (Label)this.Page.FindControl("updatepanelid").FindControl("labelname") as Label;
```

this should happen in a button_click event

Does anyone have any experience with this type of issue?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FindControl doesn't always work as expected. Try this recursive function and use your line of code that you have up top.

```
 public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control ctlRoot, string sControlId)
    {
        // if this control is the one we are looking for, break from the recursion    
        // and return the control.    
        if (ctlRoot.ID == sControlId)
        {
            return ctlRoot;
        }
        // loop the child controls of this parent control and call recursively.    
        foreach (Control ctl in ctlRoot.Controls)
        {
            Control ctlFound = FindControlRecursive(ctl, sControlId);
            // if we found the control, return it.        
            if (ctlFound != null)
            {
                return ctlFound;
            }
        }// we never found the control so just return null.    
        return null;
    }
```

Your call would look something like this.

```
var ridname = (RealWorld.Grids.FrozenGridView)FindControl(this, "gridname") as RealWorld.Grids.FrozenGridView;
```

Comment: this worked and thank you!! but the rows of the grid are still not accessable, it just shows zero for the rows, do you have any tips as to why that could be happening.